# c# How to process the string?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I connect to a webservice that gives me a response something like this(This is not the whole string, but you get the idea):

sResponse = "{\"Name\":\" Bod\u00f8\",\"homePage\":\"http:\/\/www.example.com\"}";

As you can see, the "Bod\u00f8" is not as it should be.
Therefor i tried to convert the unicode (\u00f8) to char by doing this with the string:

```
     public string unicodeToChar(string sString)
     {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (char chars in sString)
         {
             if (chars >= 32 && chars <= 255)
             {
                 sb.Append(chars);
             }
             else
             {
                 // Replacement character
                 sb.Append((char)chars);                  
             }

         }
         sString = sb.ToString();
        return sString;
    }
```

But it won't work, probably because the string is shown as \u00f8, and not \u00f8.

Now it would not be a problem if \u00f8 was the only unicode i had to convert, but i got many more of the unicodes.
That means that i can't just use the replace function :(

Hope someone can help.

Comment: uhm... i see now that the unicodeToChar function does not really help me at all :P
My fault... tired :P

Answer (score 1):

You're basically talking about converting from [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)](http://json.org). Try this link--near the bottom you'll see a list of publicly available libraries, including some in C#, that might do what you need.

Comment: The Json is already beeing parsed by myself, i only need to solve this problem :P

Or do you know of a library that kan parse this json to an array:

{\"Topic\":{\"001\":{\"ItemHeader\":\"Test\",\"ItemText\":\"Comment\"}},\"Image\":{\"001\":{\"ItemImage\":\"www.image.com\",\"ImageDescription\":\"description\"}}}

If you do, please leave an example to, please :)

Answer (score 1):

The excellent [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) library has no problems decoding unicode escape sequences:

```
var sResponse = "{\"Name\":\"Bod\u00f8\",\"homePage\":\"http://www.ex.com\"}";
var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sResponse);
var name = ((JValue)obj["Name"]).Value;
var homePage = ((JValue)obj["homePage"]).Value;
Debug.Assert(Equals(name, "Bodø"));
Debug.Assert(Equals(homePage, "http://www.ex.com"));
```

This also allows you to deserialize to real POCO objects, making the code even cleaner (although less dynamic).

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(sResponse);
Debug.Assert(obj2.Name == "Bodø");
Debug.Assert(obj2.HomePage == "http://www.ex.com");

public class Response
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HomePage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sounds great, but when i have tried to add the JSON.net library earlier it has taken all the memory on my device.


And one more thing that i see i have written wrong.

The problem with unicode was that the string was like this:
var sResponse = "{\"Name\":\"Bod\\u00f8\",....etc   }"

Notice that after "Bod" it is two slashes, not one. That is my real problem. And i can't just replace the \\u00f8 with \u00f8, because there will be more unicodes in my string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to try:

```
string character = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(chars);
sb.Append(character);
```

Comment: nah, since the function was wrong, this will probably not work.

The function takes each character, and therefor does not process the \u00f8

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is getting quite old, but I crashed into this problem as of today, while trying to access the Facebook Graph API. I was getting these strange \u00f8 and other variations back.

First I tried a simple replace as the OP also said (with the help from an online table). But I thought "no way!" after adding 2 replaces.

So after looking a little more at the "codes" it suddenly hit me...

The "\u" is a prefix, and the 4 characters after that is a hexadecimal encoded char code! So writing a simple regex to find all \u with 4 alphanumerical characters after, and afterwards converting the last 4 characters to integer and then to a character made the deal.

My source is in VB.NET

```
            Private Function DecodeJsonString(ByVal Input As String) As String
            For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\\u(\w{4})").Matches(Input)
                Input = Input.Replace(m.Value, Chr(CInt("&H" & m.Value.Substring(2))))
            Next
            Return Input
            End Function
```

I also have a C# version here

```
 private string DecodeJsonString(string Input)
    {
        foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\\u(\w{4})").Matches(Input))
        {
            Input = Input.Replace(m.Value, ((char)(System.Int32.Parse(m.Value.Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier))).ToString());
        }
        return Input;
    }
```

I hope it can help someone out... I hate to add libraries when I really only need a few functions from them!